# Converting RGB to Grayscale with C ARM NEON

Tags: c, neon

I am working on a project that needs to convert an RGB .bmp image to a grayscale .bmp image using ARM NEON.

I have the following problem: the converter does not convert the image properly, the resulting image is half black and on the other half it adds 3 images in grayscale. Besides this, the three images have some stripes. I have attached the code and two screenshots with the input image and the resulting one. Can you help me with a solution?

**Input image:**
[image: Input image]

**Output image:**
[image: Output image]

**Code:**

```
void rgb_to_gray(uint8_t* in, uint8_t* out, int size) {
    int i;
    uint8x8_t rfac = vdup_n_u8(77);
    uint8x8_t gfac = vdup_n_u8(150);
    uint8x8_t bfac = vdup_n_u8(29);
    uint8x8_t shift = vdup_n_u8(8);
    uint16x8_t sum;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i += 24) {
        // Load 24 bytes (8 pixels) of RGB data
        uint8x8x3_t rgb0 = vld3_u8(&in[i]);
        uint8x8x3_t rgb1 = vld3_u8(&in[i+8]);
        uint8x8x3_t rgb2 = vld3_u8(&in[i+16]);

        // Convert RGB to grayscale
        sum = vmull_u8(rgb0.val[0], rfac);
        sum = vmlal_u8(sum, rgb0.val[1], gfac);
        sum = vmlal_u8(sum, rgb0.val[2], bfac);
        sum = vmlal_u8(sum, rgb1.val[0], rfac);
        sum = vmlal_u8(sum, rgb1.val[1], gfac);
        sum = vmlal_u8(sum, rgb1.val[2], bfac);
        sum = vmlal_u8(sum, rgb2.val[0], rfac);
        sum = vmlal_u8(sum, rgb2.val[1], gfac);
        sum = vmlal_u8(sum, rgb2.val[2], bfac);

        // Shift and store the result
        uint8x8_t gray = vshrn_n_u16(sum, 8);
        vst1_u8(&out[i/3], gray);
    }
}


int main() {
    FILE *fp_in, *fp_out;

    // Load the RGB input image
    fp_in = fopen("input.bmp", "r");
    fp_out = fopen("output.bmp", "w+");
    //fread(in, sizeof(uint8_t), WIDTH*HEIGHT*3, fp_in);
    uint8_t byte[54];
    
    if(fp_in==NULL)                                     
    {                                           
        printf("Error.\n");
    }

    // Citirea header-ului BMP
    uint8_t bmp_header[54];
    fread(bmp_header, 1, 54, fp_in);
    int width = *(int*)&bmp_header[18];
    int height = *(int*)&bmp_header[22];
    int bytes_per_pixel = *(int*)&bmp_header[28];
    
    printf("Width: %d\n",width);
    printf("Height: %d\n",height );
    printf("Bytes: %d\n",bytes_per_pixel );
    int size = height*width;                                
    
    printf("Size: %d\n",size ); 
    
    uint8_t in[width*height*3];
    uint8_t out[width*height];
    fwrite(bmp_header, 1, 54, fp_out);
    
    fread(in, sizeof(uint8_t), width*height*3, fp_in);
    

    // Convert to grayscale
    rgb_to_gray(in, out, width*height*3);


    fwrite(out, sizeof(uint8_t), width*height , fp_out);
    
    fclose(fp_in);
    fclose(fp_out);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide the actual input/output image (only converted to PNG), as opposed to poorly cropped (and in the case of output also scaled) screenshots.

Comment: One issue I see right off the bat is that you're directly reusing the BMP header from the input input for the output. That means you're claiming that the output is also RGB, but provide only 1/3 of the necessary data. Since BMP with positive height has the rows in reverse order (first row is on the bottom of the image) you see smaller copies of the image at the bottom part of the output. Since you're interpreting 3 adjacent grayscale columns as a RGB triple, the images are scaled down to 1/3, and contain weird colors and stripes.

Comment: Also note that generally the colour order in a BMP is BGR, not RGB, so right now you're weighing the components incorrectly. Another thing that may nab you, as you're not handling it at all, is the fact that each row needs to be padded to a length that's a multiple of 4 bytes.

Comment: Finally, it seems that `rgb1` and `rgb2` (and everything that uses them) should be removed from the `for` loop. You say "Load 24 bytes (8 pixels) of RGB data" -- from what I gather from the docs, that's what a single call to `vld3_u8` does (including deinterleaving), and 8 pixel's worth of RGB data is what a single `uint8x8x3_t` holds. The indices used (`in[i+8]` and `in[i+16]`) don't make sense either -- if you were to unroll the loop to handle 24 **pixels** in single iteration, the offsets would be multiples of 24 (3*8 bytes), and you'd need 2 more `sum`'s...

Comment: You should get to know the memory layout prior to worrying about the algorithm.

Comment: I'd be worried that you're allocating memory for the image(s) on the stack. I can imagine many platforms where that wouldn't work.

Comment: What you need isn't an answer but a tutor.